# How to create multiple / different custom types with list comprehension?

Tags: haskell

So I want to calculate all the possible moves for a chess like game. While I calculate them, I want to store them in a special data structure, so it will be easy to output all the moves as a string of the form (Stepts, Start, End)
One example for a move would be "2, 1-1, 3-1"  With a step size of 2 we went from 1-1 to 3-1.

For this, I created custom data types and want to create multiple instances of them during a list comprehension and construct different data types at the same time. 
So far I am not sure, how to fix the syntax or if this even is possible in Haskell.

So far I was able to create 1 custom data type in a list comprehension, like this :

```
    [ Position  x y | x<- [1..5] , y<-[1..5]]
```

But I want to create multiple positions during one list comprehension, I would assume it would be:

```
    [ Position  x y, Position x y | x<- [1..5] , y<-[1..5]]
```

But that results in :

```
    error: parse error on input ‘|’
```

This is how I defined my custom types :

```
    data Move = Move{  steps:: Int
                 , start:: Position
                 , end  :: Position
                 } deriving (Read, Show, Eq)

    data Position = Position{
                x_pos:: Int
                , y_pos  :: Int
                } deriving (Read, Show, Eq)
```

In the end I would like to do something like this :

```
    [ Move(x, Position  1 1, Position x y ) | x<- [1..5] , y<-[1..5]]
```

Comment: Use `do`-notation: `do {x <- [1..5]; y <- [1..5]; [Position 1 1, Position x y]}`

Comment: Wow awesome that works thanks!!! I will read up about do, just started learning Haskell

Comment: @ckloan Might be worth knowing that in this particular case, the `do` notation is just a fancy way of writing this: `concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> [Position x y, Position y x]) [1..5]) [1..5]`, where `concatMap` is literally just `concat` (turn a lists of lists into a list, i.e. `[[a]] -> [a]`) and `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution provided by AJFarmar using do notation :

```
    do {x <- [1..5]; y <- [1..5]; [Position 1 1, Position x y]}
```

Answer (score 5):

You've got two possibilities:

1. return a list of lists of positions:

   ```
   [ [Position  x y, Position x y] | x<- [1..5] , y<-[1..5]]
   ```

   and then you can merge them into single list using `concat`:

   ```
   concat [ [Position  x y, Position x y] | x<- [1..5] , y<-[1..5]]
   ```
2. Just use `do` notation:

   ```
   do
     x <- [1..5]
     y <- [1..5]
     [ Position 1 1, Position x y]
   ```

Comment: If you're already in a list comprehension, I find `[v | ..., v <- e]` cleaner than `concat [e | ...]`.